# In laravel, whether my get request param is too long?

Tags: php, laravel

I am a learner in laravel. I try to process a confirmation_code. That is used to sent to a user email. And then the user can click the email to confirm his information.

The url is like "localhost/laravel/public/reset/$2y$10$UFEQ8HLCbqHhGsCVA445MetqaV5FOAb4eIPFqw0YCws8MpWvImR/q".

My route.php has the config such as

```
Route::get('/reset/{token}', 'AuthController@showReset');
```

In my AuthController, the function showReset is following:

```
public function showReset($token)
{
    var_dump($token);die;
}
```

if the url is "localhost/laravel/public/reset/1234", it will dump 1234. However, if the url is "localhost/laravel/public/reset/$2y$10$UFEQ8HLCbqHhGsCVA445MetqaV5FOAb4eIPFqw0YCws8MpWvImR/q", it will not come into the function showReset. It is an error of "Pipe not found."

if I use "localhost/laravel/public/reset/" . urlencode('$2y$10$UFEQ8HLCbqHhGsCVA445MetqaV5FOAb4eIPFqw0YCws8MpWvImR/q'), the result is also the same.

Whether this get request is too long? I am not sure. But the token must be unique and after reset the token is invalid.

I do not know how to fix this problem in laravel. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The / in the link

```
localhost/laravel/public/reset/
    $2y$10$UFEQ8HLCbqHhGsCVA445MetqaV5FOAb4eIPFqw0YCws8MpWvImR/q
                                                              ^ here
```

causes laravel to route it to another route, like

```
 Route::get('reset/foo/bar','Controller@index');
```

You can use [**urlencode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to fix this.

```
$href = 'localhost/laravel/public/reset/'.urlencode('
$2y$10$UFEQ8HLCbqHhGsCVA445MetqaV5FOAb4eIPFqw0YCws8MpWvImR/q');
```

Comment: It is not working either. After I do it. The url becomes "localhost/laravel/public/reset/%242y%2410%24UFEQ8HLCbqHhGsCVA445MetqaV5FOAb4eIPFqw0YCws8MpWvImR%2Fq"

Comment: yes, after urlencode it must be %242y%2410%24UFEQ8HLCbqHhGsCVA445MetqaV5FOAb4eIP‌​Fqw0YCws8MpWvImR%2Fq. But, on your var_dump($token); you will see this: $2y$10$UFEQ8HLCbqHhGsCVA445MetqaV5FOAb4eIPFqw0YCws8MpWvImR/q

Comment: Yes, but it is still cannot access the route if token is too long.

Comment: I doubt the token length is the problem. Easy way to test it? Does it work if you remove the `/` from the token?

Comment: yeah, you are right, I got the problem. Because of the "/", which is produced by hash, it caused it cannot work.